# Error in Mapper Task in Hadoop 2.2 using MultilineJSON format

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I am getting the below errors when I try to run the Map task while parsing a MultilineJSONFormat data.I have all the ncessary JARs and the program is compiling without any errors.
The input is as below :

```
    [
        {
            "SeasonTicket": false, 
            "name": "Vinson Foreman", 
            "gender": "male", 
            "age": 50, 
            "email": "vinsonforeman@cyclonica.com", 
            "annualSalary": "$98,501.00", 
            "id": 0
        }, 
        {
            "SeasonTicket": true, 
            "name": "Genevieve Compton", 
            "gender": "female", 
            "age": 28, 
            "email": "genevievecompton@cyclonica.com", 
            "annualSalary": "$46,881.00", 
            "id": 1
        }
]
```

I am trying to get the count of gender:male or female attribute.
Please see the below code:

Mapper class:

```
public  class DemoMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text> {
     private Text k = new Text();
      private Text v ;

    @Override  
    protected void map(LongWritable key , Text value, Context context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        String line = value.toString();
        StringTokenizer itr = new StringTokenizer(line);
            while (itr.hasMoreTokens()) {
                  //String token = itr.nextToken();
                k.set((itr.nextToken()));
                    context.write(k, v);
            }
    }
}
```

Reducer class :

```
public class DemoReducer extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable>

{
    //@Override
    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable <IntWritable> values,
            Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

                int sum = 0;
                while ((Iterable) values.iterator() != null) {

                    IntWritable value = values.iterator().next();
                        sum += value.get(); // process value*/
                }

            context.write(key, new IntWritable(sum));
          }
}
```

Main class:

```
public final class ExampleJob extends Configured implements Tool {

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
        int res = ToolRunner.run(new Configuration(), new ExampleJob(), args);
        System.exit(res);
    }

     /**
     * The MapReduce driver - setup and launch the job.
     *
     * @param args the command-line arguments
     * @return the process exit code
     * @throws Exception if something goes wrong
     */
    public int run(final String[] args) throws Exception {

        Configuration conf = super.getConf();

      //  writeInput(conf, new Path(input));

        Job job = new Job(conf);
        job.setJarByClass(ExampleJob.class);
        job.setOutputKeyClass(LongWritable.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
        job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setMapOutputValueClass(LongWritable.class);

        job.setMapperClass(DemoMapper.class);
        job.setReducerClass(DemoReducer.class);
        job.setCombinerClass(DemoReducer.class);
       // job.setNumReduceTasks(1);


        Path path = new Path("result15");

        FileInputFormat.addInputPaths(job, "testfolder");
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, path);

        // use the JSON input format
        job.setInputFormatClass(MultiLineJsonInputFormat.class);

        // specify the JSON attribute name which is used to determine which
        // JSON elements are supplied to the mapper
        MultiLineJsonInputFormat.setInputJsonMember(job,"gender");

        if (job.waitForCompletion(true)) {
            return 0;
        }
        return 1; 
       }
}
```

StackTrace:

```
    SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
2014-04-06 18:30:33,662 WARN  [main] util.NativeCodeLoader (NativeCodeLoader.java:<clinit>(62)) - Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
2014-04-06 18:30:33,878 INFO  [main] jvm.JvmMetrics (JvmMetrics.java:init(76)) - Initializing JVM Metrics with processName=JobTracker, sessionId=
2014-04-06 18:30:34,352 WARN  [main] mapreduce.JobSubmitter (JobSubmitter.java:copyAndConfigureFiles(258)) - No job jar file set.  User classes may not be found. See Job or Job#setJar(String).
2014-04-06 18:30:34,379 INFO  [main] input.FileInputFormat (FileInputFormat.java:listStatus(287)) - Total input paths to process : 1
2014-04-06 18:30:34,459 INFO  [main] mapreduce.JobSubmitter (JobSubmitter.java:submitJobInternal(394)) - number of splits:1
2014-04-06 18:30:34,482 INFO  [main] Configuration.deprecation (Configuration.java:warnOnceIfDeprecated(840)) - user.name is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.user.name
2014-04-06 18:30:34,484 INFO  [main] Configuration.deprecation (Configuration.java:warnOnceIfDeprecated(840)) - mapred.output.value.class is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.output.value.class
2014-04-06 18:30:34,485 INFO  [main] Configuration.deprecation (Configuration.java:warnOnceIfDeprecated(840)) - mapred.mapoutput.value.class is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.map.output.value.class
2014-04-06 18:30:34,486 INFO  [main] Configuration.deprecation (Configuration.java:warnOnceIfDeprecated(840)) - mapreduce.combine.class is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.combine.class
2014-04-06 18:30:34,487 INFO  [main] Configuration.deprecation (Configuration.java:warnOnceIfDeprecated(840)) - mapreduce.map.class is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.map.class
2014-04-06 18:30:34,487 INFO  [main] Configuration.deprecation (Configuration.java:warnOnceIfDeprecated(840)) - mapreduce.reduce.class is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.reduce.class
2014-04-06 18:30:34,488 INFO  [main] Configuration.deprecation (Configuration.java:warnOnceIfDeprecated(840)) - mapreduce.inputformat.class is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.inputformat.class
2014-04-06 18:30:34,488 INFO  [main] Configuration.deprecation (Configuration.java:warnOnceIfDeprecated(840)) - mapred.input.dir is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.inputdir
2014-04-06 18:30:34,489 INFO  [main] Configuration.deprecation (Configuration.java:warnOnceIfDeprecated(840)) - mapred.output.dir is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.output.fileoutputformat.outputdir
2014-04-06 18:30:34,489 INFO  [main] Configuration.deprecation (Configuration.java:warnOnceIfDeprecated(840)) - mapred.map.tasks is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.maps
2014-04-06 18:30:34,490 INFO  [main] Configuration.deprecation (Configuration.java:warnOnceIfDeprecated(840)) - mapred.output.key.class is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.output.key.class
2014-04-06 18:30:34,495 INFO  [main] Configuration.deprecation (Configuration.java:warnOnceIfDeprecated(840)) - mapred.mapoutput.key.class is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.map.output.key.class
2014-04-06 18:30:34,496 INFO  [main] Configuration.deprecation (Configuration.java:warnOnceIfDeprecated(840)) - mapred.working.dir is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.working.dir
2014-04-06 18:30:34,881 INFO  [main] mapreduce.JobSubmitter (JobSubmitter.java:printTokens(477)) - Submitting tokens for job: job_local1580542852_0001
2014-04-06 18:30:35,005 WARN  [main] conf.Configuration (Configuration.java:loadProperty(2172)) - file:/tmp/hadoop-riak/mapred/staging/riak1580542852/.staging/job_local1580542852_0001/job.xml:an attempt to override final parameter: mapreduce.job.end-notification.max.retry.interval;  Ignoring.
2014-04-06 18:30:35,006 WARN  [main] conf.Configuration (Configuration.java:loadProperty(2172)) - file:/tmp/hadoop-riak/mapred/staging/riak1580542852/.staging/job_local1580542852_0001/job.xml:an attempt to override final parameter: mapreduce.job.end-notification.max.attempts;  Ignoring.
2014-04-06 18:30:35,412 WARN  [main] conf.Configuration (Configuration.java:loadProperty(2172)) - file:/tmp/hadoop-riak/mapred/local/localRunner/riak/job_local1580542852_0001/job_local1580542852_0001.xml:an attempt to override final parameter: mapreduce.job.end-notification.max.retry.interval;  Ignoring.
2014-04-06 18:30:35,413 WARN  [main] conf.Configuration (Configuration.java:loadProperty(2172)) - file:/tmp/hadoop-riak/mapred/local/localRunner/riak/job_local1580542852_0001/job_local1580542852_0001.xml:an attempt to override final parameter: mapreduce.job.end-notification.max.attempts;  Ignoring.
2014-04-06 18:30:35,437 INFO  [main] mapreduce.Job (Job.java:submit(1272)) - The url to track the job: http://localhost:8080/
2014-04-06 18:30:35,439 INFO  [main] mapreduce.Job (Job.java:monitorAndPrintJob(1317)) - Running job: job_local1580542852_0001
2014-04-06 18:30:35,441 INFO  [Thread-12] mapred.LocalJobRunner (LocalJobRunner.java:createOutputCommitter(323)) - OutputCommitter set in config null
2014-04-06 18:30:35,453 INFO  [Thread-12] mapred.LocalJobRunner (LocalJobRunner.java:createOutputCommitter(341)) - OutputCommitter is org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter
2014-04-06 18:30:35,543 INFO  [Thread-12] mapred.LocalJobRunner (LocalJobRunner.java:run(389)) - Waiting for map tasks
2014-04-06 18:30:35,545 INFO  [LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] mapred.LocalJobRunner (LocalJobRunner.java:run(216)) - Starting task: attempt_local1580542852_0001_m_000000_0
2014-04-06 18:30:35,689 INFO  [LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] mapred.Task (Task.java:initialize(581)) -  Using ResourceCalculatorProcessTree : [ ]
2014-04-06 18:30:35,700 INFO  [LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] mapred.MapTask (MapTask.java:runNewMapper(732)) - Processing split: file:/home/riak/workspace/Hadooprun/testfolder/file1.json:0+7703579
2014-04-06 18:30:35,733 INFO  [LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] mapred.MapTask (MapTask.java:createSortingCollector(387)) - Map output collector class = org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer
2014-04-06 18:30:36,585 INFO  [main] mapreduce.Job (Job.java:monitorAndPrintJob(1338)) - Job job_local1580542852_0001 running in uber mode : false
2014-04-06 18:30:36,588 INFO  [main] mapreduce.Job (Job.java:monitorAndPrintJob(1345)) -  map 0% reduce 0%
2014-04-06 18:30:36,593 INFO  [LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] mapred.MapTask (MapTask.java:setEquator(1183)) - (EQUATOR) 0 kvi 26214396(104857584)
2014-04-06 18:30:36,593 INFO  [LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] mapred.MapTask (MapTask.java:init(975)) - mapreduce.task.io.sort.mb: 100
2014-04-06 18:30:36,594 INFO  [LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] mapred.MapTask (MapTask.java:init(976)) - soft limit at 83886080
2014-04-06 18:30:36,594 INFO  [LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] mapred.MapTask (MapTask.java:init(977)) - bufstart = 0; bufvoid = 104857600
2014-04-06 18:30:36,594 INFO  [LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] mapred.MapTask (MapTask.java:init(978)) - kvstart = 26214396; length = 6553600
2014-04-06 18:30:36,622 INFO  [LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] mapred.MapTask (MapTask.java:flush(1440)) - Starting flush of map output
2014-04-06 18:30:36,649 INFO  [Thread-12] mapred.LocalJobRunner (LocalJobRunner.java:run(397)) - Map task executor complete.
2014-04-06 18:30:36,652 WARN  [Thread-12] mapred.LocalJobRunner (LocalJobRunner.java:run(482)) - job_local1580542852_0001
java.lang.Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:403)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer.collect(MapTask.java:1054)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewOutputCollector.write(MapTask.java:691)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.TaskInputOutputContextImpl.write(TaskInputOutputContextImpl.java:89)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.map.WrappedMapper$Context.write(WrappedMapper.java:112)
    at main.java.com.alexholmes.json.mapreduce.DemoMapper.map(DemoMapper.java:25)
    at main.java.com.alexholmes.json.mapreduce.DemoMapper.map(DemoMapper.java:1)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:145)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:763)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:339)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job$MapTaskRunnable.run(LocalJobRunner.java:235)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
2014-04-06 18:30:37,594 INFO  [main] mapreduce.Job (Job.java:monitorAndPrintJob(1358)) - Job job_local1580542852_0001 failed with state FAILED due to: NA
2014-04-06 18:30:37,605 INFO  [main] mapreduce.Job (Job.java:monitorAndPrintJob(1363)) - Counters: 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at the stack trace

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
...
at main.java.com.alexholmes.json.mapreduce.DemoMapper.map(DemoMapper.java:25)
```

In the mapper the member "Text v" is never initialized but got written to context.

```
private Text v ;
...
context.write(k, v);
```

You will need to initialize "v" to new Text()

Answer (score 1):

In addition to aasoj's answer, I would like to make a point here that the output from the mapper will be fed as input to reducer. So, in your reducer class the input key value types are 'Text' and 'IntWritable' where as the output key values of your mapper class are 'Text' and 'Text'.

Try to change the input key values of reducer same as the mapper's output types which looks like as below:

public  class DemoMapper extends Mapper

public class DemoReducer extends Reducer

Apart from the above everything looks for me.

Comment: In my above answer mapper and reducer's parameters are missing.

Comment: public  class DemoMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text> {


public class DemoReducer extends Reducer<Text, Text, Text, IntWritable>